# Cannot get store (Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias)

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to Sencha Touch 2, and trying to learn it by following this [tutorial](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-2/). I'm getting an error when I open `index.html`. Here's the error:

```
[Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.noteslist
sencha-touch-debug.js:6295 Uncaught Error:
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Following hekomobile's advice, I made a few changes. The requires property is now:

```
requires: [
        'NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer',
        'NotesApp.view.NotesList'
],
```

Also, putting the itemTpl property string all on one line seemed to fix the problem (sorta).

Part of the app loads (The top toolbar loads), but the store doesn't, and I'm getting this error:

`[WARN][NotesApp.view.NotesList#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found Console.js:35`

The current state of the code for this project can be downloaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?e4986489llyskpu).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Into app.js archive put `requires: ['NotesApp.your_folder.your_class']` something like this

```
Ext.application({
name: 'NotesApp',

    requires: ['NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer'],

    views: ['NotesListContainer'],
    controllers: ['Notes'],
    models: ['Note'],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
           xtype: 'noteslistcontainer'
        })
    }
});
```

and so on. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Adding `requires: ['NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer'],` to my `app.js` file didn't fix it. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What ???, remove `alias: 'widget.noteslistcontainer',`and put `type:'noteslistcontainer',`. What do you want to show?

Comment: I think you mean `xtype: 'noteslistcontainer'`, but that still gives me the same error. The app should look like [this](http://i.imgur.com/PbzpV.png), but looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/aBNCT.png).

Comment: Using `type:` instead of `xtype:` gives the very first error I posted. Did you mean `type` or `xtype`?

Comment: No problem :) I found another error, which took care of my problem. The writer of the tutorial forgot to add the line `stores: ['Notes']` in `app.js`. As soon as I added that, it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Nathan put correct itemTpl something like this,

```
itemTpl: '<pre><div class="list-item-title">{title}</div><div class="list-item-narrative">{narrative}</div></pre>'
```

in your .js file this wrong. :)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I did this.